# Any way to use [ =IFERROR ] for text?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm using `=IFERROR(A1,"ERROR In Cell")`
Problem is my data has been converted in a way what all errors like #NA, #VALUE converted into plain text. Now when I use `=IFERROR(A1,"ERROR In Cell")` it returns #NA or #VALUE again not "ERROR In Cell" which i'm expecting to.

Seems Google spreadsheet can't delect #NA, #VALUE as error when they are imported as plain text. Please let me know how can I use `=IFERROR(A1,"ERROR In Cell")` above situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the "errors" start with the character # perhaps try

`=IF(LEFT(A1)="#","ERROR In Cell",A1)`